# R: date/time "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD" import

Tags: r, datetime-format

How can I import the folowing date/time format  example in R ? I'm willing to keep all information within this format.

```
2016-09-12T09:47:00.000+0200
```

where:

```
 YYYY = four-digit year
 MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
 DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
 hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
 mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
 ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
 s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
 TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

I've tried `strptime` without success since I cannot find how to match `s` and `TZD`, example:

```
> strptime("2016-09-12T09:47:00.000+0200", format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z')
[1] "2016-09-12 09:47:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match the decimal fraction of a second (from the docs ?strptime in Examples) use:

```
format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z'
```

Then, to see the 3-digits:

```
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
strptime("2016-09-12T09:47:00.123+0200", format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS%z')
##[1] "2016-09-12 03:47:00.123"
```

To go back to not seeing the 3-digits:

```
options(op)
```

I believe this does parse the offset from UTC (i.e., the `+0200`). I'm on the east coast of the United States, and it is EDT (-0400). Therefore, I'm 6 hours behind (+0200) so that `09:47:00.123+0200` becomes `03:47:00.123` EDT.

Comment: Wow, thanks ! I've missed the %OS ... how can I be sure it's GMT+2 (in my case I live in France): do I have to rely on the fact it will automatically convert to your local time zone ? maybe I'll have to add a "GMT+2" to the result ...

Comment: @guzu92: Yes, I believe `strptime` automatically converts to your local time based on your locale if it sees the offset from UTC. I believe you can set the locale, but I've never done that before.

Comment: @guzu92: I should add that if you don't use the UTC offset (and don't use `%z`) at the end, then `strptime` interprets that as your local time.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the (pretty new) [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package which does this *without formats*:

```
R> anytime("2016-09-12T09:47:00.000+0200")
[1] "2016-09-12 09:47:00 CDT"
R>
```

I may try to extend it to also recognize the trailing TZ offset as the underlying [Boost date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time.html) code supports it. However, I have so far followed R and taken to interpret the time as *local time* for which it also (automatically) finds the local timezone.

[anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) also supports fractional seconds automatically (but you need to ensure you display them):

```
R> anytime("2016-09-12T09:47:00.123456+0200")
[1] "2016-09-12 09:47:00.123456 CDT"
R>
```

I tend to work with microsecond data so I tend to have six digits on all the anyway as shown here.