# how to parse time and date correctly

Tags: r

im having some issues when trying to parse date/time from this csv

```
NAME                 LATITUDE   LONGITUDE   DATE   REPORT_TYPE   SOURCE   DailyAverageWindSpeed   DailyPrecipitation
WICHITA FALLS MUNICIPAL AIRPORT TX US   33.9786   -98.4928   2020-07-01T00:52:00   FM-15   7      
WICHITA FALLS MUNICIPAL AIRPORT TX US   33.9786   -98.4928   2020-07-01T01:52:00   FM-15   7      
WICHITA FALLS MUNICIPAL AIRPORT TX US   33.9786   -98.4928   2020-07-01T02:52:00   FM-15   7      
WICHITA FALLS MUNICIPAL AIRPORT TX US   33.9786   -98.4928   2020-07-01T03:52:00   FM-15   6
```

This is the code i have so far.

```
X2509750 <- read_csv("weather.csv", 
                     col_types = cols(STATION = col_skip(), 
                                      ELEVATION = col_skip(), 
                                      DATE = col_datetime(format = "%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S")))

Warning: 305532 parsing failures.
row  col                    expected              actual          file
  1 DATE date like %Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S 2020-07-01T00:52:00 'weather.csv'
  2 DATE date like %Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S 2020-07-01T01:52:00 'weather.csv'
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534842/r-date-time-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-stzd-import)

Comment: `parse_datetime("2020-07-01T03:52:00")`, used by `col_datetime`, works perfectly well (but assumes UTC). One issue is the incorrect period in your format string. The other is timezone conversion. You could read the datetimes as character, then convert using `lubridate::ymd_hms`.

Comment: `X2509750 <- read_csv("weather.csv") %>% mutate(DATE = ymd_hms(DATE))` should work.